# How do I save 9patch image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I am using a image, and I would like to draw 9 patch for that image. I am not sure in which format i have to save this. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653661/how-to-create-9-patch-in-photoshop-what-is-9-png-encoding) help?

Content:

Here are the basic rules for creating a 9-patch:

- The outer 1px margin can contain only 100% black (RGB 0, 0, 0) or fully transparent.
- The black pixels for the top margin and left margin define the stretch points, and must be either a solid line, a single point, or two separate points. If two points are defined, it will stretch equally between the two.
- The black pixels for the bottom margin and right margin define the content area. These pixels must be one contiguous line.

When saving, be sure to **append the .9.png extension**.

[image]

[image]